# Any ideas of how to use array to store the name of other variables?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, list, data-structures

I've just finished writing JavaScrip code, and I'am wondering if we can use the array to store the variable name and make use of it.

Suppose this is my AJAX response text

```
[{"NumOfColumn" : "11"},{"t_id" : "TSK_000001","t_name" : "Reviewing project's user"}]
```

As you can see, this array consists of 2 objects that have different variable names.

And this is how I normally handle with the received set of data.

```
var arr = JSON.parse(this.data);
  for(i = 1; i < rows ; i++)
    {
        out += "<tr><td>"+
                arr[i].t_id +
                "</td><td>" +
                arr[i].t_name+
        out += "</td></tr>";
    }
table.childNodes[5].innerHTML = out;
```

Is there any idea of how can we make the array or list to store the variable's name (t_id,i_name) 
 ,return them, then automatically concatenate with the arr[i] variable. So that 
we don't need to write like `arr[i].t_id , arr[i].t_name,...`

**More explanation to the question.**

Assume that you get the AJAX response like

```
[{"a" : "Hello,"b" : "World"}]
```

and the other one like

```
[{"c": "cat", "d": "meow"}] .
```

Traditionally, if I would like to get the data from one of these objects, I had to write the code like

```
arr[i].a + arr[i].b
```

to get data for the first object. then for the second object

```
arr[i].c + arr[i].d
```

My question is,Are there any ideas of how can we **GET** and **store** the variable name of each object before we process to get the data?

If there is a solution, then, you wouldn't need wirte a code like this anymore.

It would be

```
arr[i].(something that stores a,b and c,d or other varies from different objects ).
```

It's really hard for me to explain the idea. Please leave some comment

Thank you.

Comment: Can you please describe the output you want in greater detail?

Comment: [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) - return array of keys from object, you can use [`bracket notation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) for using getted keys

Comment: solution - use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
var namesArray = [];
for(var i = 0; i< test.length; i++){
    for(var me in test[i]){
        namesArray.push(me);
     }
}
```

Assuming that test is your response array.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear. But, if you are looking for a way to create an array which should contain names of all properties of an object, then you can do it as shown below.

```
var obj = { 
  t_id: "TSK_000001" ,
  t_name: "Reviewing project's user"
};

var arrayOfPropertyNames = [];

for(var propertyName in obj){
  arrayOfPropertyNames.push(propertyName);

}

console.log(arrayOfPropertyNames);
```

Comment: The variable name of each objects from the received AJAX request are not the same. I mean, I really want to know if anyone has any ideas of building a flexible system that capable of returning data from objects that have different kinds of structure.

Answer (score 0):

for getting keys from object you can use [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) function.
this function return array of keys, so you can use jey from it with [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation)

so, code would be something like this

```
var arr = JSON.parse(this.data);
for(i = 1; i < rows ; i++)
{
    var o = arr[i];
    out += "<tr>" + Object.keys(o).map(function(key){
      return "<td>" + o[key] + "</td>";
    }).join('') + "</tr>";
}
```

or even

```
out += JSON.parse(this.data).slice(1).map(function(o){
    return "<tr>" + Object.keys(o).map(function(key){
      return "<td>" + o[key] + "</td>";
    }).join('') + "</tr>";
}).join('');
```